# Firebase Analytics Debug Mode + BuddyBuild

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics, buddy-build

In order to enable **Firebase Analytics Debug Mode** we need to add this flag

```
-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
```

to Xcode as described in [the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start).

[image]

### However...

... this only works when we launch the app from Xcode. When we deploy the app via BuddyBuild the argument is lost.

### My question

How can I enable Firebase Analytics Debug Mode when the app is deployed via BuddyBuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's indeed not possible with buddybuild. Even with a shared scheme, the arguments passed on launch are set by iOS once you run the app from a device.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to decrease the refresh rate, which I assume was your goal.

Answer (score 0):

This is designed so that you can't ship the Debug Mode with the app because it will spam the system log and send debug traffic.

Answer (score 0):

⚠️☢️ Be careful. make sure you **DON'T** use this code in **PRODUCTION** builds.

Here is an extension that swizzles `arguments` property of `ProcessInfo` class

```swift
extension ProcessInfo {
    @objc dynamic func swizzled_arguments() -> [String] {
        self.swizzled_arguments() + Self.additionalArguments
    }

    static var additionalArguments: [String] = [] {
        willSet {
            swizzleArgumentsProperty
        }
    }

    static let swizzleArgumentsProperty: Void = {
        let originalGetter = class_getInstanceMethod(ProcessInfo.self, #selector(getter: arguments))
        let swizzledGetter = class_getInstanceMethod(ProcessInfo.self, #selector(swizzled_arguments))
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalGetter!, swizzledGetter!)
    }()
}
```

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
/// ...
    ProcessInfo.additionalArguments.append("-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled")
    ProcessInfo.additionalArguments.append("-FIRDebugEnabled")

    FirebaseApp.configure()
/// ...
}
```

I hope it will help somebody.